# Does module_invoke() work for non core modules?

Tags: hooks

I tried using `module_invoke('casrel','nodeapi', $node, 'view')`, but what I get for  `casrel_nodeapi()` is a truncated `$node` and "load" instead of "view".

Does anybody have an idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [module_invoke_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7). The [module_invoke](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) function only invokes a module in a specific module (casrel.module in your example).

By the way, you usually do not need to invoke hook_nodeapi yourself. The node module invokes hook_nodeapi when necessary, if you just use the api functions (like [node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/7)) correctly. If you need to alter a node before it's viewed, you need to *implement* hook_nodeapi instead of invoking it.

Comment: marcvangend, thank you for your comment - I'm making a batch to visit all nodes of certain type trying to apply casrel_nodeapi - it doesn't work because $op should be 'view' and it becomes 'load' and $node reaches truncated

Comment: So can't you just call node_view() or node_build_content() on all nodes of that type?

Comment: It seems the OP is interested in invoking the hook for just a module. While I agree about not invoking `hook_nodeapi()` directly, this answer doesn't explain why invoking `hook_nodeapi('view')` has the result of invoking `hook_nodeapi('load'). I get something is wrong with the code the OP is using.

Comment: Kiam, maybe you are right, I may have misunderstood the intentions of the OP.

Comment: surely your right, kiam, I was calling module_invoke with a $node I built myself - now I call node_page_view($node); before calling module_invoke and it works fine - thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> Does `module_invoke()` work for non core modules?

Yes, it does. For `module_invoke()` there isn't a difference between core modules, and third-party modules as the function doesn't verify the module being called is contained in a particular list, and Drupal doesn't have a way to know if a module is a Drupal core one, or not. 
There are many third-party modules that use `module_invoke()`, and none of them has issues with the function (if it is called with the right parameters).

I agree with marcvangend that you are invoking `hook_nodeapi()` directly when you should be using a function that Drupal make available. Still, if you are having issues with `module_invoke()`, then there is something wrong with your code, or you are not tracing correctly all the calls to the implementation of `hook_nodeapi()` for that module.
For example, when a module implements `hook_nodeapi()`, that hook is called from Drupal code. Are you sure that `casrel_nodeapi('load')` is being called from Drupal core, and it is not what `module_invoke('casrel','nodeapi', $node, 'view')` is causing? Consider that Drupal always invoke `hook_nodeapi('load')` before `hook_nodeapi('view')` because a node is first loaded, and then shown.